# Expansion of a number in exponential function-ish series

Tags: number-theory

> Prove that every positive rational number can be expressed uniquely as a finite sum of the form:
>
> $$ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{a_i}{i!}$$
> Where $a_n$ are integers such that $ 0 \leq a_n \leq n-1$ for all $n>1$
>
> ISI UGB BMath 7/18/2021

I am not sure how this series even came about, but I proved a very specific part of the result. I proved that if such a decomposition exists then it is unique. I did this by assuming two numbers $n_1= \sum_i \frac{a_i}{i!}$ and $n_2 = \sum_i \frac{a_i}{i!}$, then it is found that $n_1 =n_2$ and so a contradiction occurs, meaning there is only one number having this decomposition.

Comment: Obviously a single sum has only one value.  The uniqueness part of the question means that no two different sums of this sort have the same value.